# mysql trigger "without" FOR EACH ROW

Tags: mysql, triggers

I design one application to analyse counting frequentation data on different places in one city.

I have one data table (hereinafter referred to `DT`) for each counting site designed like this : `startDate` (DATETIME), `dataCount`(INT).
Every records contain the start date of counting and the number of accessed front the counter. the number of accesed is clear at each record. interval of record depends of the counter (hourly data in general).

I have one table (hereinafter referred to `resumeDT`) to summarize all my counting site : name, `dateReference`, `location`, `description`... AND `dailyAvg`.

I would like create one trigger of this type :

```
CREATE TRIGGER avgDT AFTER UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE ON DT
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE resumeDT SET avg= (SELECT AVG(tmp.sum) 
FROM (SELECT sum(count) FROM DT GROUP BY DATE(date)) tmp)
WHERE dateReference="DT"
```

What is a bit troubling for me is that if I insert 500 values at one time, I will execute in addition 500 UPDATE. I would like execute my update query only once at the end.
I know that `FOR EACH ROW` is obligatory in the syntax of triggers but could I find one workaround to do what I want?

Maybe use trigger just to increment one mysql variable `@DTChanged` and call one external script which scan `@DTChanged` every second. `if (@DTChanged!= 0 and lastDTChanged==@DTChanged)` (no insert or update for 1s) => update of `resumeDT`

Have you got any advice or other solution?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not possible, MySQL does not have statement level triggers, only row level triggers. Btw: `date` and `count` are *horrible* names for columns. For one because they are reserved words, and secondly (and more important) they don't document at all what they store. A "start date"? An "end date"? A "recording date"? A "valid until date"?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I edit my question to be more explicit.

Comment: That doesn't change  my comment. There is no way you can achieve this with a trigger in MySQL.

Comment: Maybe one workaround or any advice to do what I want without use triggers?

Answer (score 1):

The issue over triggers is a concept called RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row). Standard triggers (the most used, and simple to implement) are usually row based

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic642789-338-1.aspx

Im not aware of statement based triggers for MySQL. But they do exist for other database engines (RDBMS)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger

Solutions on this case

1) On other databases, there's a standard feature called Materialized Views. The ones which updates automatically could fit in your needs. The issue is that for each updated done on the table(s), it will trigger a refresh that takes resources and time to finish, and that will impact on your transaction time. Some databases, like DB2, are able even to use the summarized data for queries not even referencing the summarized table, given its optimizer capabilities.

2) Regarding MySQL, given its openness, its possible to scope on the transaction / binary log, where all the changes made to database are recorded (This is also called Stream Processing). To scope on this information is called (Binary Log) Change Data Capture. The tool maxwells-daemon below allow you to capture and process  the changes made so far. There's even another tools which simulates a Materialized View (flexviews)

http://maxwells-daemon.io/

https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/08/27/trawling-the-binlog-with-flexcdc-and-new-flexcdc-plugins-for-mysql/

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/flexviews/

Remember that the binary log will only 'valid'/'useful' after the transaction commit, so , there's probably a delay that will happen if your CDC do handle this. Better to check it out